# Проблема с ботом для погоды на discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Всем привет. Возникла ошибка на pyhton 3.8. Имеется такой вот код для бота который отображает погоду в дискорде

```
import discord
import requests,json
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return
 @client.command()
        async def weather(ctx, *, city: str):

            city_name = city
            complete_url = base_url + "appid=" + api_key + "&q=" + city_name
            response = requests.get(complete_url)
            x = response.json()
            channel = ctx.message.channel
            if x["cod"] != "404":
                async with channel.typing():
                    y = x["main"]
                    current_temperature = y["temp"]
                    current_temperature_celsiuis = str(round(current_temperature - 273.15))
                    current_pressure = y["pressure"]
                    current_humidity = y["humidity"]
                    z = x["weather"]
                    weather_description = z[0]["description"]
                    weather_description = z[0]["description"]
                    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Weather in {city_name}",
                                          color=ctx.guild.me.top_role.color,
                                          timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, )
                    embed.add_field(name="Descripition", value=f"**{weather_description}**", inline=False)
                    embed.add_field(name="Temperature(C)", value=f"**{current_temperature_celsiuis}°C**", inline=False)
                    embed.add_field(name="Humidity(%)", value=f"**{current_humidity}%**", inline=False)
                    embed.add_field(name="Atmospheric Pressure(hPa)", value=f"**{current_pressure}hPa**", inline=False)
                    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://i.ibb.co/CMrsxdX/weather.png")
                    embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}")
                    await channel.send(embed=embed
```

После запуска и ввода команды !weather New Delhi появляется ошибка

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pythonProject16\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:/pythonProject16/discord-bot.py", line 88, in on_message
    @client.command()
AttributeError: 'MyClient' object has no attribute 'command'
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно исправить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы объявляете `commands.Bot()`, но в основном классе не используете его. В основном классе у вас используется `discord.Client()`.

Ошибка как-раз таки указывает на то, что объект клиента не имеет атрибута *command*.

---

**Дополнено:**

Если вы новичок, я думаю вам будет непринципиально как работать - через класс или без него.

**В данный момент у вас такая структура кода:**

```
# импорты
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

# токен
TOKEN = 'token'

# класс объекта discord.Client()
class MyClient(discord.Client):

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Hello')

# запуск класса
client = MyClient()
client.run(TOKEN)
```

**А можно сделать тоже самое, только без класса:**

```
# импорты
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

# токен
TOKEN = 'token'

# объект
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Hello')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

---

Что касается вашего кода, если вкратце - есть 2 типа ботов

1. `discord.Client()` - клиент, бот, не умеет выполнять команды (`@client.command()`)
2. `commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')` - бот для команд

Вы в своем коде объявляете бота для команд: `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')`, но не используете его, так как основной код у вас находится в классе `class MyClient(discord.Client)`, объектом которого (в скобках) является `discord.Client()`, не умеющий выполнять команды.

Вообщем, в вашей ситуации есть 2 выхода:

1. Избавиться от класса, то есть привести верхний код к формату нижнего, и работать уже с ботом для команд.
2. Продолжить работать с классом, но указать в скобках объект бота для команд, то есть `class MyClient(commands.Bot):` и при вызове указывать префикс: `client = MyClient(command_prefix='>')`

Comment: Не могли бы вы сказать где  именно мне необходимо исправить код(Что нибудь добавить или убрать) Я в питоне полный новичок и для меня немного сложно ориентироваться во всем этом

Comment: @ИгорьМокривский, вроде расписал все как есть, надеюсь понятно :)

*Если что, можете скинуть мне полный код, я переделаю его как надо - время у меня есть*

Comment: Вот создал новый вопрос   https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1207584/%d0%95%d1%89%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-discord-py